# Possible to upgrade from 15.04 Unity to 15.10 Gnome?

Tags: upgrade

Is it Possible to upgrade from 15.04 Unity to 15.10 Gnome?  If not, why not?

Comment: It is not impossible, but might not be a good idea.

Comment: You upgrade your 15.04 Ubuntu with Unity Desktop to 15.10 (still with Unity) and then additionally install the Gnome Desktop and select it in the login screen. You don't need to remove Unity (and you probably should not...)

Answer (score 1):

What you want is basically a 2 part problem:

1. you upgrade to 15.10 with Unity.
2. you install gnome (and optionally remove Unity).

So it is possible to go from 15.04 Unity to 15.10 Gnome but it is not a direct method so it is not "upgrading" from 15.04 Unity to 15.10 Gnome).

It is probably quicker and smarter to do a re-install of 15.10 with Gnome. It would clean your system from anything related to Unity. Just make sure not to overwrite your personal files (I use a separate partition named /discworld for my personal files that I never format during a re-install).

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to say in my comment ;D